# How to Convert NSNumber in Objective C to Java Long

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, mobile, servlet-3.0

`NSNumber *idValue =[NSNumber numberWithLong:[result longLongValue]];`

Above result value is "2174767089" , idValue is "-2120200207" .It got converted.

By mistake I sent this NSNumber to my Server.

Accepting Param in Server (Java Servlet) is Long. In Java Service, I am getting **"-2120200207"**. Wanted to convert this back to **"2174767089"**. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use BigInteger type but you need to alter your database with big integer equal type (if you are using database).

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to construct an `NSNumber` with a `longLongValue`, but the constructor you're calling is for a `longValue`.

```
NSNumber *idValue =[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[result longLongValue]];
if ([idValue longLongValue] == [result longLongValue]) {
  NSLog(@"Of course it does.");
}
```

Incidentally, a Java `Long` is the same length as an Objective-C `long long`: 64 bits. An Objective-C `long` is a pseudonym for `int`.

Comment: I found , in java..... 
long idValue = 2174767089L;
int intVal = (int)(idValue); System.out.println(" idValue = " +intVal); // Prints "-2120200207". How to get back "2174767089" from int in java?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. In Java, `long` and `int` are not the same datatype. The maximum value of an `int` in Java is `2147483648`.  If you need to store a value larger than this, you *must* use `long` to do so.

Comment: Yeah ! I got it and Fixed issue. Thank you